# Methods to solve a compound distribution MLE I can't write in closed form

Tags: maximum-likelihood, gibbs, optimization

What are some methods of solving a MLE parameter estimate where the likelihood function can't be written in closed form?

I have a compound distribution that I don't have a closed form for (no conjugate priors here :( ). I guess it's almost like a hierarchical Bayesian model, but instead of providing a prior distribution, I just want to compute the parameter estimates for the "prior" that'll give me the maximum likelihood estimate.

For example, in a Bayesian framework,  one can use Gibbs sampling to get at a posterior distribution without solving the complete integral.  I guess I need something like that. But in this case, I don't want to give an initial prior distribution in the first place, I just want the maximum likelihood estimate of its parameter.

Any ways to solve a compound distribution MLE that can't be written in closed form?

Comment: Any reason you cannot use numerical optimization?